# How to start a JavaFX application in a standalone process

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, multiprocessing

I'd like to start a JavaFX application, if it isn't already running.

The JavaFX application is packaged in a JAR container, which is in the classpath of the calling application. The calling application should execute the JavaFX app.

The JavaFX application should not terminate if the calling application gets terminated. (therefore it needs to be in a separate process)

I tried the following approach, but even though `uiProcess.isAlive()` returns true, the JavaFX application is never visible.

```
// caller main thread
String[] startOptions = new String[]{"java", "-jar", "javafx-ui.jar"}; 
Process uiProcess = new ProcessBuilder(startOptions).start();
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

UPDATE:

I created a helper class which takes the JAR name and tries to execute it. Unfortunately this doesn't work. But if I copy the the logged CLI command and execute the command in a terminal, the app is started as expected. If I print `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` property, I see that my javafx-ui.jar is on the classpath.

Usage:

```
    ProcessExecutor processExecutor = new ProcessExecutor();
    processExecutor.executeJarByName("javafx-ui.jar");
```

Executor:

```
public class ProcessExecutor {
    private List<Process> processes;

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessExecutor.class);

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ProcessExecutor() {
        processes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Executes jar in a standalone process
     *
     * @param jarName
     */
    public Process executeJarByName(String jarName) throws IOException {
        String[] command = new String[]{"java", "-jar", jarName};
        ProcessBuilder builder = createProcessBuilder(command);
        Process process = builder.start();
        processes.add(process);

        if (process.isAlive()) {

            Optional<ProcessHandle> processHandle = ProcessHandle.of(process.pid());
            if (processHandle.isPresent()) {
                ProcessHandle.Info processInfo = processHandle.get().info();
                logger.info("COMMAND: {}", processInfo.command().orElse(""));
                logger.info("CLI: {}", processInfo.commandLine().orElse(""));
                logger.info("USER: {}", processInfo.user().orElse(""));
                logger.info("START TIME: {}", processInfo.startInstant().orElse(null));
                logger.info("TOTAL CPU: {}", processInfo.totalCpuDuration().orElse(null));
            }
        }
        return process;
    }

    private ProcessBuilder createProcessBuilder(String[] command) {
        return new ProcessBuilder(command);
    }

    /**
     * Kills all executed processes
     */
    public void killAll() {
        processes.forEach(p -> p.destroy());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you execute successfully the Jar file alone by console?

Comment: @NikiforosArchakis yes, that's no issue.

Comment: I suggest you include the JavaFX Jar as a library in your starter app and then just load your Main View

Comment: @NikiforosArchakis But this would start the JavaFX application in the same process as the starter app? If I terminate the starter, the JavaFX application will terminate too. `Application.launch((Class<? extends Application>) myFXClazz);`

Comment: The javafx-ui.jar seems to terminate very fast, but only if I call `uiProcess.waitFor()`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, if I execute the following command, using the Java ProcessBuilder. The `mainClassName` needs to be the fully qualified class name of the class, containing the `main()` method. (including the package name)

```
    String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String java = javaHome + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";

    String[] command = {java, "-cp", classpath, mainClassName};
    ProcessBuilder builder = createProcessBuilder(command);
```